# jmeter java scoket exception

Tags: java, jmeter, socketexception

I am running load test to read data from my application.
My system is Jmete2.10
             Java 1.6
             Apache Tomcat

I am running a http request with 200 users with loop count 1.

It run's successfully some times but i get socket exception error for some of the users.
I checked my application logs and there was not error.
But Jmeter is showing this error

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Apache tomcat by default process only 150 ( if i remember correctly) concurrent requests. If you expect to serve more than that, you need to increase the limit

in order to increase it open up server.xml and add maxThreads="200" under your connector

follow the tomcat documentaion http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Could it be an OS socket limit?

Comment: @viren, i hope you've started tomcat once you did the change in server.xml